# Getting different result on OKHTTP from postman

Tags: java, android, postman, okhttp

I am trying to get some data from server. the main problem is I don't have the server access, but of course I know the request details, I am using PostMan for the testing server calls and than implementing them on android using OkHttp.

Here is what I get from server on android side using both HttpUrlConnection or OkHttp :

> {"collection":{"version":"1.0","href":"http://development.abc.com:80/","links":[{"href":"#","rel":"header","prompt":"Students"},{"href":"#","rel":"header","prompt":"CFAs"},{"href":"signup","rel":"header
>   trial","prompt":"Free Trial"},{"href":"about","rel":"footer
>   sidebar","prompt":"About"},{"href":"testimonials","rel":"footer
>   sidebar","prompt":"Testimonials"},{"href":"contact","rel":"footer","prompt":"Contact"},{"href":"faq","rel":"footer
>   sidebar","prompt":"FAQs"},{"href":"login","rel":"login","prompt":"Login"}],.......

I am using the same headers on both sides i.e

```
("accept", "application/vnd.collection+json")
("authorization", "Basic secret==")
```

and using the same credentials for test login:

Strangely, same server call is giving below data in PostMan

> { "collection": { "version": "1.0", "href":
>   "http://development.abc.com:80/ch/re/videos",
>   "links": [ { "href":
>   "http://development.abc.com:80/ch/re/vr",
>   "rel": "menu vrated", "prompt": "V rated" }, { "href":
>   "http://development.abc.com:80/user/watcr", "rel": "menu
>   watchlater", "prompt": "Watch later" }...

Here is my code:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
            cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);

            OkHttpClient client =new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .cookieJar(new CookieJar() {


                        @Override
                        public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {
                            cookieStore.put(url, cookies);
                            cookie=cookies.get(0).toString();


                        }

                        @Override
                        public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
                            List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.get(url);
                            return cookies != null ? cookies : new ArrayList<Cookie>();
                        }
                    })
                    .build();


            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://development.abc.com/login")
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("accept", "application/vnd.collection+json")
                    .addHeader("authorization", "Basic secret==")
                    .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                    .addHeader("Cookie",cookie)
                    .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .build();



            Response response = null;
            try
            {

               response=client.newCall(request).execute();
                String str=response.body().string();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

How can the same server call returning different results.

I checked from " [results from Curl is different than results from Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060365/results-from-curl-is-different-than-results-from-postman) " that one should also need to add `user agent` in header so I also tried this one but no luck.

One more thing that If I use the wrong credentials (i.e. body: email,password) for this call I get same error on both Okhttp and PostMan.

Thanks.

Comment: Debug the HTTP calls using an interceptor such as Fiddler or Charles. You can then compare whether the two requests are identical or not. You may have to talk with the server guys too!

Comment: okay, will try thanks alot.

Comment: Try using this interceptor and seeing what curl command is run

https://github.com/mrmike/Ok2Curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out the problem with this.

Acutally its a redirecting issue, need to talk with server guys.
What I do to make it work is

- make a login server call
- got the cookie from server
- save the cookie
- again made the server call along with the cookie in header

and yes here it is the same data as with postman.

Thanks Every one :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced a similar problem where I got a successful postman response ( an encrypted body ) and a malformed encrypted response from OkHttp.

turns out my Interceptor  was added as

```
OkHttpClient.Builder().addNetworkInterceptor(MyInterceptor());
```

I was able Resolved by changing (.addNetworkInterceptor) to (.addInterceptor)